# ScrollTop от элемента равен 0

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Приветствую. У меня сложилась трудность при написании jquery скрипта.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var bo = $('.header').scrollTop();
        $('body').append(bo);
    })
})
```

при скролинге страницы выводит 0, а если писать так

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var bo = $(window).scrollTop();
            $('body').append(bo);
        })
    })
```

то все нормально, но мне нужно именно от элемента.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: > но мне нужно именно от элемента

Что "от элемента" вам нужно?

Comment: киньте на http://jsfiddle.net пример вашей разметки, скорре всего не от того элемента scrollTop берете, подозреваю, что надо для его родителя смотреть...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, не в разметке дело. **.scrollTop()** и **.scrollLeft()** выдают величину скроллинга элементов, но в примере ТС скроллится не элемент с классом *.header*, а страница в целом. Вопрос надо бы точнее сформулировать. А точнее, понять что в процессе прокрутки надо получить.

Comment: @Deonis для div'а с oveflow:scroll тоже будут scrollTop и scrollLeft. вполне возможно что речь идет и об этом тоже.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, правильно, но в этом случае надо событие [вешать на этот элемент](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/2DVF4/2/), но никак не на окно.

Comment: Deonis, спасибо, ваш пример работает. А без overflow: scroll никак не обойтись?

Comment: @Arteom, у элемента div, по умолчанию нет прокрутки. Если вас смущает горизонтальная полоса прокрутки, то можно указать для него свойство:

    overflow-y: scroll;
    /* или */
    overflow-y: auto;

Тогда в первом случае скролл будет только по вертикали, а во втором - будет появляться по вертикали, если контент выходит за рамки размеров, указанные для элемента.